# Left join MySql/PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Whilst populating a table based on ids and labels from different tables, it appeared apparent there must potentially be a better way of achieving the same result with less code and a more direct approach using `LEFT JOIN` but i am puzzled after trying to work out if its actually capable of achieving the desired result.

Am i correct in thinking a `LEFT JOIN` is usable in this instance?

Referencing two tables against one another where one lists id's related to another table and that other table has the titles allocated for each reference?

I know full well that if theres independent information for each row `LEFT JOIN` is suitable, but where theres in this case only several ids to reference for many rows, i just am not clicking with how i could get it to work...

The current way i am achieving my desired result in PHP/MySQL

```
$itemid = $row['item_id'];

$secid = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM item_groups WHERE item_id='$itemid' ");
while ($secidrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($secid)) {
    //echo $secidrow["section_id"]; //testing
    $id = $secidrow["section_id"];

    $secnameget = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM items_section_list WHERE item_sec_id='$id' ");
    while ($secname = mysql_fetch_assoc($secnameget)) {
        echo $secname["section_name"];  
    }
}
```

Example of the data
Item groups
:drink
:food
:shelf

Item List
itemId, groupId

Group List
groupId, groupTitle

The idea so outputting data to a table instead of outputting "Item & Id Number, in place of the ID Number the title actually appears.

I have achieved the desired result but i am always interested in seeking better ways to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Perfect time to use a left join (at least in my opinion). I've posted an answer that should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've deciphered your code properly, you should be able to use the following query to get both values at the same time.

```
$itemid = $row['item_id'];

$secid = mysql_query("
    SELECT * 
    FROM item_groups 
    LEFT JOIN items_section_list
      ON items_section_list.item_sec_id = item_groups.section_id
    WHERE item_id='$itemid'
");

while ($secidrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($secid)) {
    //$id = $secidrow["section_id"];
    echo $secidrow["section_name"];
}
```